# display facebook page dialog with ios sdk

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm working with ios, and I'm trying to show a facebook page to let user like it.

There is a dialog method in facebook ios sdk

```
[facebook dialog: andDelegate:]
```

But i can't use this method, because there are "feed","oauth" methods only.

1. Is there any function to show facebook page with a dialog?

I guess there isn't.

So the second try is this : Sign in with Webview, and show user the page.

This has a problem too. i can't sign in facebook via webview with user's access token.

i've done signin with "[facebook authorize:fbPermissions]" method, but this never share the cookie with my UIWebView.

1. Can I sign in facebook via webview, with user's access token?

And more try, I thought like this.

If i sign in with UIWebView first, and save access token in my server and my iphone, I could use this for ios sdk.

Is this possible?

Please help me. I didn't sleep for a long time.

Thanks.